# How to write a tester file?

Tags: c++

I've a problem, with some misunderstanding and code-writing.

I have two object files. 
Makefile :

```
double :
    g++ double.cpp -o Int
create :
    g++ create.cpp -o Create
```

Now I want to write some program, which make so : 
launch ./Create with parameter N (from 2 to 1024 f.e.). and then launch ./Int.

Any hints ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to 'launch' programs? Seems like you want a single program that calls into other functions.

Comment: @Jeffrey I want to call "./Create N , ./Int" for N = 2 ... 1024 and get the result.
I don't know how to write some script or something like that.

Comment: @openspace, is your question about C++, about writing a script or about doing this in the Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may implement it using a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd <path-to-executables>


for i in {2..1024}
do
    ./Create $i
    ./Int
done
```

Comment: May we write smht like i *= 2 instead of i+=1?

Comment: you may increment i within the for loop body, e.g. `$i = $i * 2`

Answer (score 2):

You should use a single program, linking everything together:

```
g++ double.cpp create.cpp main.cpp -o program
```

Have a single `main` function. Use includes where needed:

Main.cpp

```
#include "double.h"

int main()
{
    for(int i=2; i<1024; i++)
   {
        Double::function(i);
```

But without seeing your function definition, it's hard to give a precise answer